# View Holder with float

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, adapter, android-viewholder

I'm trying to make a recyclerView adapter using viewHolder. In that recyclerView, I need to use a float value, and I have no idea how to use viewHolder with float. I tried :

```
viewHolder.price.setText(nData.get(i).getPrice());
```

but Android Studio says that it could not resolve method getPrice because it returns an int instead of a float. What should I do to make this right?

Comment: price is a textview? from the error message it sounds like something is actually going wrong inside the getPrice method, causing it to return an integer instead of the float value that the method is supposed to return?

Comment: No, price is supposed to be a float value, but I don't actually know how to set a float value with onBindViewHolder on a Recycler Adapter...

Answer (score 1):

Use this line:

```js
viewHolder.price.setText(String.valueOf(nData.get(i).getPrice()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
viewHolder.price.setText(Float.parseFloat(nData.get(i).getPrice()));
```